# Why is the process running on the background?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This situation can be easily produced on your test database.
Say I open table for edition in SSMS 2008 (Right click ->Edit Top 200 Rows). This opens new tab for me. I close the tab and still can see this process in Activity Monitor for some time. The question: why is it running even though I have closed original and what does define running time in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug of SQL Server 2008. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: it's a client/server application. You close the tab on the client-side, but the (apparently long running) server code isn't notified immediately or can't stop immediately.

Comment: That's strange because when I open the tab it is shown immediately, but when I close the tab it seems like there is a lag.

Comment: It gets fired off immediately, but that doesn't mean it can always stop immediately.

Comment: It starts and stops immediately on SQL Server 2005, but on 2008 it's certainly not the case. Let's see if anyone else comes up with interesting ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't persisting a connection. It's the lag in Activity Monitor.

If you query sysprocesses directly, the connection drops straight away

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Sysprocesses WHERE sys.sysprocesses.nt_username LIKE '%gbn%'
```

Comment: Does not look like it. Just did it again. Both Activity Monitor (even when refreshing) and your script show "ghost" process

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov: well, it doesn't happen for me.

Comment: What edition are you testing on? It does not happend on my SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, but I get it on my SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 Enterprise with SSMS 2008.

Comment: I assume need 2008 engine to get this.